# Gdb GUI front-end which support gdb CLI

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have tried various front-ends for gdb but I did not notice in any of them an option to interact with gdb directly (issuing CLI commands).

Is there a gdb front-end which supports this? I am mainly interested in memory examining functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is of course much more than GDB front-end, but it does provide a console view, where you can [interact with GDB directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177897/how-can-i-enter-commands-to-a-gdb-prompt-while-debugging-with-eclipse-cdt).

[image: eclipse debug view with gdb console shown]

It also provides (at least) two different memory views, plus third party plug-ins that allow you to examine "bare metal" peripheral registers - if this is what you want to do.

You can do all this with [Eclipse for C/C++ developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr1). There is now also a [standalone debugger build of Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/StandaloneDebugger) which I did not try yet, but should be lighter version of above focused only on debugging.

Once you start Eclipse (for which you will need Java 7) you will need to create a launch configuration for C/C++ application, then launch it in Eclipse. 
[image: eclipse launch configurations]

Or even better import you project into eclipse and create launch configuration for that project.

Comment: Hi i can't see it in my eclipse. i'm using linux gdb7.6 eclipse neon. is there something i'm missing or it's a bug?
thanks

Comment: Go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Debugger Console. It seems to have been modified in Neon.2. (https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn92)

Comment: Thanks very much!